# In Unity, how to make gui box with outline

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try following code but box disappear

```
public class TestUIBorder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GUISkin skin;

    void OnGUI()
    {
        skin.box.border = new RectOffset(10, 10, 10, 10);
        GUI.Box(new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200), "This is a box", skin.box);
    }
}
```

like following screenshot, without text and without outline

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to make a GUI for in game or are you trying to write a new editor control for the editor? If you are making a in game GUI you should NOT be calling OnGUI, and instead be working with the [new UI System](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/user-interface-ui) (which actually is rather old by now) for anything that is displayed in game. OnGUI is only used for designing controlls for the UnityEditor itself now.

Comment: ... therefore what you currently see in the game view is "nothing" just the Sky Background. There isn't even a box ;)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62224353/how-to-show-an-outlined-gui-box-in-unity/62224354#62224354