# How to show an outlined GUI Box in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like to show a transparent GUI.Box on screen with a colored border. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a PNG image with a transparent center and a border with your desired thickness. The size of the image doesn't matter, but the border around the image should be your desired border size. For instance, I created the 64 x 64 image with a 2px green border on [Pixilart](https://www.pixilart.com/draw).

[image]

2. Add the PNG as a 2D texture in your project. You can drag the image from Finder into your Assets pane to do this.
3. Use the following GUI.Box invocation:

```
public Texture2D BoxBorder; // Set this to your border texture in the Unity Editor

void OnGUI()
{
    var borderSize = 2; // Border size in pixels
    var style = new GUIStyle();
//Initialize RectOffset object
    style.border = new RectOffset(borderSize, borderSize, borderSize, borderSize);
    style.normal.background = BoxBorder;
    GUI.Box(new Rect(/* rect position */), GUIContent.none, style);
}
```

Comment: Step 1 can still be made within Unity. Just create a new `Texture2D` and color it with `BorderColor` and the middle pixel with `Color.clear`. Do make sure the filter is set to "point" and then apply it.

Answer (score 1):

This draws 2 boxes, one smaller than the other to achieve the border.

I don't know how to get the background colour of a regular editor box, so I sampled the colour used these values to set my own Color variable.

```
public static void DrawUIBox(Rect rect, Color borderColor, Color backgroundColor, int width = 2)
{
    Rect outer = new Rect(rect);
    Rect inner = new Rect(rect.x + width, rect.y + width, rect.width - width * 2, rect.height - width * 2);
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(outer, borderColor);
    EditorGUI.DrawRect(inner, backgroundColor);
}

Color backgroundColour = new Color32(194, 194, 194, 255);
Rect borderRect = new Rect(2, 2, position.width - 4, position.height - 4);
DrawUIBox(borderRect, Color.gray, backgroundColour, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void DrawBorderRect(Rect area, Color color, float borderWidth)
    {
        //------------------------------------------------
        float x1 = area.x;
        float y1 = area.y;
        float x2 = area.width;
        float y2 = borderWidth;

        Rect lineRect = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        EditorGUI.DrawRect(lineRect, color);

        //------------------------------------------------
        x1 = area.x + area.width;
        y1 = area.y;
        x2 = borderWidth;
        y2 = area.height;

        lineRect = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        EditorGUI.DrawRect(lineRect, color);

        //------------------------------------------------
        x1 = area.x;
        y1 = area.y;
        x2 = borderWidth;
        y2 = area.height;

        lineRect = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        EditorGUI.DrawRect(lineRect, color);

        //------------------------------------------------
        x1 = area.x;
        y1 = area.y + ControlArea.height;
        x2 = area.width;
        y2 = borderWidth;

        lineRect = new Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        EditorGUI.DrawRect(lineRect, color);
    }
```